# Update/insert only a column of database table in PHP

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I WordPress table named wp_fes_vendors, there is a total of 12 columns.

Out of these 12 columns, I want to only update the data of column name **requests**

The data i am getting for this column is from a custom form in backend stored in `$_POST['getval']`

Here is code i tried

```
 if (!empty(isset($_POST['getval'])))
    {       
            global $wpdb;
            $table_name=$wpdb->prefix.'fes_vendors';

            $data_array = array(

            'requests' => $_POST['getval']


            );

            $data_where = array('requests' => $_POST['getval']);

            $wpdb->update($table_name,$data_array,$data_where);


    }
```

Html

```
<form id="myForm" name="myform" action="" method="POST" style="padding:20px;">
  <label> Select if this Vendor wishes to receive customer requests or not: </label>
  <select name="getval" id="brandSel" size="1">
      <option selected="selected" disbaled value="">-- Select status --</option>
      <option value="1">Enable</option>
      <option value="0">Disable</option>
  </select>

  <?php submit_button('submit'); ?>
</form>
```

I tried several times but the data is not being saved /updated.
Here is picture of db

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition doesn't make sense.

Lets say that the user picked `enable` -> `$_POST['getval'] = 1;`

Your query would be:

> Update {table} SET requests = 1 WHERE requests = 1

- Since none of the records have a value of 1 in the requests column, that condition would never exist and the update won't happen.
- Even if there were rows with "requests = 1", the update won't really change them as their value is already 1.
- The same goes for the case where the user picks "disable" (0)

I believe you should update your condition to a specific row.
You can do it by adding a hidden input to the form with the specific row you wish to update. And update your condition to so it would be something like:

```
"id" => $_POST['row_id']
```

Comment: I need to select a particular row in that case, is that what you are trying to say?

Comment: Yes, and you do it by using a field that identifies that row. **OR** you can still update multiple rows but you need to rely on a value that identifies them. Usually that would be the "id" column.

Comment: it worked the way you mentioned, but in the form html the data saved in db is not being shown. I mean once the data is updated in that column, in the form section the selected data need to be shown. To get id i used $data_where = array('id' => $_GET['id']);